# how to make can a TextField content's type can be number and letter if obscureText property is true

Tags: flutter

using a `TextField` and its `obscureText` property is `true`, how can I input some letter, now only the number can be input

```
obscureText:true,
textInputFormatter: WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9]"))
```

I want to make the `TextField`'s input can be both letters and numbers

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 1):

The `obscureText` property should not matter.

If you want to input letters and numbers,
then you have to use the `keyboardType` property.

For example:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.text
```

BR

Answer (score 0):

**keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,**

```
TextFormField(
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            focusNode: secondFocusNode,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            controller: emailController,

          ),
```